# Binding problem using multiselect listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to bind a listbox with a List like this:

```
lbAssignedTo.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValues",
  RequirementEditorNodeWrapper.ActiveRecord, "RefAssigned", true,
  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

The problem is that "SelectedValues" property of the listbox has always the same value, no mather what items i have selected in the listbox

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use the propert "DataSource" if you are using a generic List as a source?
you can do:

```
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null); //while list is a List<T> variable
```